# Prove that $E$ has measure $0$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Been trying to solve this problem for a couple of days now:

Let $E \subset \mathbb{R}$. Prove that if there exists $0 \leq \delta < 1$ such that for every interval $[a,b]$ we have $$|E\cap[a,b]|_e \leq \delta(b-a),$$ then $|E|_e = 0$. Here $|-|_e$ is the exterior Lebesgue measure.